# phablet-dev-bootstrap does not proceed

Tags: ubuntu-touch, porting

I would like to try to port Ubuntu Touch for a Desire S I have borrowed for a while. However, phablet-dev-bootstrap fails:

```
[...]

object e76efdd7b342577c40aa271fa5ded9d66a783a9b
type commit
tag v1.12.4
tagger Conley Owens  1380645867 -0700

repo 1.12.4

gpg: Podpisano wto, 1 paź 2013, 18:44:27 CEST z użyciem RSA kluczem o ID 692B382C
gpg: Nie można sprawdzić podpisu: brak klucza publicznego
error: could not verify the tag 'v1.12.4'
```

Has anyone experienced such an error and found any solution?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and found this StackOverflow question that seems to have fixed the issue for others:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19126603/android-source-repo-gpg-public-key-not-found

I didn't read it correctly the first time, and the thing I did wrong was to download the repo file to `~/bin/repo`. What I had to do was type `which repo`, and then copy the newly downloaded file over this one (in my case this was `/usr/bin/repo`). So my steps were:

```
curl http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo >
~/bin/repo
chmod a+x ~/bin/repo
which repo 
sudo mv /usr/bin/repo /usr/bin/repo2
sudo mv ~/bin/repo /usr/bin/repo
```

This has enabled me to progress further.